# How to add image in ImageView of TableController properly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a TableViewController and custom cell. Inside of the cell i have an ImageView. Xcode 9.4
*I do not have enough reputation - so provide links.

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDQVx.png)

I have constraints settled to superview Leading-Trailing: 20, Top-Bottom:10, clip to bound enabled, Scale to fill.

When i launch application, i oversee this:

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXeRk.png)

Image shrinks down. If i change to Aspect Fit/Aspect Fill the image becomes smaller(image view is not filled) or zoomed(not all image is available).

How to fix this issue? I do not want to give it specific width/heigh for compatibility.

Maybe i should change my constraints? I have watched several tutorials, where these constraints work, even did step by step, however it does not work as supposed to.

All constraints are settled for ImageView to superView (that is cell itself).

Thanks.

Comment: what is the cell height.

Comment: I did not know where you take cell Height, but it is the heigh of Cell itself that consist of several views, such as imageView, textView and etc.  All constraints are for ImageView.

Comment: use estimatedHeightForRow tableview delegate method to give height for cell

Comment: I think here you provide scale for table cell(row) itself. But i want to manage only image without touching any part or properties of cell itself. I do not want to hardcode myself any parameters. Is that possible?

Comment: show me your code.

Comment: set estimated height for your cell `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = CGFloat(44)` and also `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so that it will grow according to your content inside. the problem here is with your image your cell getting height from your image you provided if you give fix height for your image your problem would be solved.

Comment: Thank for understanding Govind Kumawat. If i provide fixed height it will work properly, i already realized that, but then if a change iphone simulator to Ipad, then the proportion will be broken. I hope you get what i mean. The code you provide - could you please explain it little bit deeper? I do know that it will help me to manage my rowHeight, but, it still means that i have to provide it hardcoded. I found autolayout little bit confusing after web design.

Comment: first way is to get `superView` height and give your image height according to that second you can get current device type and give your image you height to that `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`. you can't do it in storyboard because you don't have access to superView in custom cell.

Comment: Anyway thanks, i have not gone that far yet in iOS, but still take into account.

Comment: @SalehAhmadzada have a look for tutorial for `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it's for Self-sizing cell but `UIElement` like `UIImageView` should have a height otherwise it will get height from image provided inside of it with the image actual dimension

Answer (score 0):

Set **estimated height** for your cell `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = CGFloat(44)` and also `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so that it will grow according to your content inside. the problem here is with your `image` your cell getting height from your `image` you provided if you give fix height for your image your problem would be solved.

to adapt height for `imageView` according to iPhone and iPad.

**First way** is to get `superView` height and give your image height according to that programmatically.

**Second** you can get current device type and give your `image` you height to that `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`. you can't do it in storyboard because you don't have access to `superView` in custom cell.